# Multiple Linux distributions return "Fast TSC calibration failed" when running on Hyper-V

Tags: linux, virtualization, hyper-v

Client Hyper-V on Windows 8.1 Pro host with Intel Core i7-4800MQ processor.

Several Linux distributions, including openSUSE and Kali Linux, return the following error message when booting up in a Hyper-V environment:

```
[0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
```

The VMs seem to run normally otherwise. Should I be concerned about this?